# FrontEnd or BackEnd encrypting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I'm building a system requiring a password. My question is, should I encrypt it frontend or backend? If I do it frontend (with javascript probably) then everyone could crack the encryption = big security issue. But if I do it backend, then the plain password has to be sent somehow which also will create a security hole. So my question is how I should do this properly?

Comment: "how I should do this properly?" - use SSL ?

Comment: use HTTPS/SSL protocol

Comment: Oh, my.. Been working all night, too tired to even think about that xD Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never try to create your own security protocols or throw around your own crypto. It is recommended to use the best standards available. To achieve what you're trying to do, I'd use a standard HTTPS/SSL protocol.  And yes, as 'damphat' mentions, salting passwords is crucial, along with latest hash functions.

Comment: I agree with this. But we should also encrypt password (with salt) to protect database. HTTPS/SSL will protect the information from man-in-the-middle-attack only.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I have edited the answer with some of the things that I missed, like salting and even strong hash functions. Appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Your encryption should be on the server.  As long as you are sending the plain text password over HTTPS, the password is safe from everyone except the NSA :)